# Arduino Mega won't read serial from XBee coordinator in API mode

Tags: arduino, xbee

I have two [XBees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee):

- One is a router AT reading and sending analog data from one analog
  pin.
- The other is a coordinator API connected to an Arduino Mega
  serial port (rx1 and tx1).

Whenever I try to read from the XBee serial in the Arduino, the readings are mostly zeros (instead of data packets as they should be).

It must be noted that using xctu terminal or any other terminal I can read the correct data with no problems whatsoever.

Here is some sample code I'm using:

```
void setup() {
    Serial1.begin(9600); // Here the XBee is connected
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial1.available()){
        Serial.print(Serial1.read());
    }
```

Comment: You have to check the connection between Xbee and the Arduino. It must be [Tx(arduino) <=> Rx(Xbee)] & [Rx(arduino) <=> Tx(Xbee)].

Comment: Isn't there a "}" missing in loop()? Or does loop() contain more code than shown? Or more code in the `if` clause?

Answer (score 0):

After hours upon hours I have finally been able to fix it. I don't know exactly why, but it seems that connecting tx1 and rx1 in reversed order has solved the problem, and now I can communicate between my XBees.

Comment: You typically connect TX (Transmit) of one device to RX (Receive) on the other.  Is that how you have it working now?